# SQL summing columns values

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I've got a table like this:

```
ID    Departure              Duration(in min)         
==============================================
1     2017-12-31 11:30:45     120
2     2017-06-16 22:31:46     240
```

And i want to sum last two columns into:

```
ID    Departure              Duration(in min)   Arrival       
============================================================
1     2017-12-31 11:30:45     120        2017-12-31 13:30:45  
2     2017-06-16 22:31:46     240        2017-06-17 02:31:46
```

How can I do this?

Departure is TIMESTAMP

And Duration INT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use ADDTIME and SEC_TO_TIME function to do your job

```
SELECT ADDTIME(Departure,SEC_TO_TIME(Duration*60)) as Arrival
```

for more 
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-addtime-function.php

and 
http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-sec_to_time-function.php

Answer (score 0):

Just add using `interval`:

```
select t.*, (departure + interval duration minute) as arrival
from t;
```

If the above doesn't work (and it should) you can always use `date_add()`:

```
select t.*, date_add(departure, interval duration minute) as arrival
from t;
```

Comment: I've got syntax Error, unexpected ')' and when i try without () I've got unexpected 'minute'

Answer (score 0):

Following MySQL query should work:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD("2017-12-31 11:30:45", INTERVAL 120 MINUTE);
```

Comment: I tryed also date_add() but still same problem

Comment: question tagged as `MySQL` and you given a `SQL Server` specific answer. What a fun!!!

Comment: Sorry. for MySQL try using SELECT DATE_ADD("2017-12-31 11:30:45", INTERVAL 120 MINUTE);

Comment: And I will adding two columns at all not just every value

Comment: select date_add(Departure, INTERVAL Duration MINUTE)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATE_ADD`-function in conjunction with `INTERVAL MINUTE`:

```
SELECT flights.*, DATE_ADD(departure, INTERVAL duration MINUTE) as arrival
from (
  SELECT '2017-12-31 11:30:45' AS departure, 120 as duration
  UNION SELECT '2017-06-16 22:31:46', 240) flights
```

Output from [rextester/mysql](http://rextester.com/l/mysql_online_compiler):

```
    departure            duration   arrival
1   2017-12-31 11:30:45  120        2017-12-31 13:30:45
2   2017-06-16 22:31:46  240        2017-06-17 02:31:46
```